# Python writing to Dataframe within a function

Tags: python, function, dataframe, assign

I am sure this must be straight forward but having been trying to solve this for a few days now, I think I know what I'm doing wrong but stumped with ideas:

I'm using a function to subset a Dataframe and based on the subset create a new column within that subset and populate it. This works but unless I assign this back to a new data frame named mod_df, I can't seen to get it back into df

Seems like after the function ends, the data is lost.

Would appreciate any thoughts

```
mod_df = []

def Pop_Gen(lower, upper, val):
    x = df[(df['byear'] >= lower) &  (df['byear'] <= upper)].assign(Gen = val)
    mod_df.append(x)

for index, row in gen_Ref_df.iterrows():
    Pop_Gen(row.lower,row.upper,row.val)
```

**Input**

1st dataframe:

```
df:

   Name  byear  
0  John  1980  
1  Mary  1990
```

2nd dataframe:

```
gen_Ref_df:

   val   lower   upper  
0  old   1970    1985  
1  new   1986    1995
```

**Current output**

```
mod_df:

   Name  byear Gen  
0  John  1980  old  
1  Mary  1990  new
```

**Expected output** (in `df` without needing to put into `mod_df`)

```
df:

   Name  byear Gen  
0  John  1980  old  
1  Mary  1990  new
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as some input, and the current and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `df` and `gen_Ref_df` having the same number of rows, I would do the following:

```py
# These should be your input DataFrame

d = {'name': ['John', 'Mary'], 'byear': [1980, 1990]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

d = {'val': ['old', 'new'], 'lower': [1970, 1986], 'upper': [1985, 1995]}
gen_Ref_df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


# Replace the for loop and the function call with a single line
# Create a new column 'Gen' in df and populate each row with the Gen val obtained by the two conditions 
df['Gen'] = gen_Ref_df[(df['byear'] >= gen_Ref_df.lower) & (df['byear'] <= gen_Ref_df.upper)].assign(Gen = gen_Ref_df.val).Gen

print(df)
```

**Result**:

```
   name  byear  Gen
0  John   1980  old
1  Mary   1990  new
```

Comment: thanks but I may not have explained the question very well. I am trying to create a new column within df called 'Gen' without needing to save to another df first like mod_df. If I try df = mod_df.append(x) I get the error "local variable 'df' referenced before assignment"

Comment: Did you try with ```df['Get'] = df[(df['byear'] >= lower) &  (df['byear'] <= upper)].assign(Gen = val)```

Comment: get the following ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 11, placement implies 1

Comment: That's probably because ```df[(df['byear'] >= lower) &  (df['byear'] <= upper)].assign(Gen = val)``` is returning a DataFrame and not a np.aray (a single column). You should update your question and provide a working example with data passed to the methods you implemented